# How to check for a certain number of a given character

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use regex in Java to split a string after a given number of ","

Say I have:

"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"

And I want to split the string at the 5th ",", what's the regex to do so?

Expected result:

"1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
"6, 7, 8, 9, 10"

I have tried using ".{30}" but this counts everything and isn't suitable. And using "\\d{30}" does not split after the 30th digit.

Thanks!

Comment: Which language? The split solution depends on look-behind. The match solution doesn't.

Comment: What would be your expected result?

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry! I have made edits to this for both of your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex for matching:

```
(?:\d+, *){4}\d+
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rH9mP0/2)

This will give you 2 matches:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

**Code:**

```
String s = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?:\\d+, *){4}\\d+");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(s);
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
while(mat.find()) {
    output.append(mat.group()).append("\n");
}
System.out.print(output);
```

**Output:**

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
6, 7, 8, 9, 10
11, 12, 13, 14, 15
```

Comment: If numbers are two digits, this would mean the regex may truncate a 2 digit number. By using regex on commas, this wont happen which is why I want to string.split() using regex on a given number of commas

Comment: This would break it up into multiple groups of 5, if he wants exactly two groups you might need to add something like ,(.*) for the second group.

Comment: This is the desired effect I would like, however, using this regex, the resulting return is [ , , ,] which is not what I want

Comment: Sorry didn't get your comment. Can you clarify with an example.

Comment: When using the string.split(your regex); method on my string " 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12," I get [ , , , ,]

Comment: Ah don't use split. I mentioned that you need to use `match` using `Pattern` and `Matcher` APIs. Let me know if you want me to post a code doing same for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68508/discussion-between-bradley-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to validate the input, then you can use this regex to match groups of 5 numbers (except the last one, where there can be 1 to 4 numbers).

By assuming that the input is valid, when there are 5 numbers ahead, the regex will always match all 5 numbers, so the only case it can match less is when there are less than 5 numbers available.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?: *, *\\d+){0,4}").matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Given the input `"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11"`, it outputs:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
6, 7, 8, 9, 10
11
```

(No leading or trailing space)

The regex will be more complex if you want to validate **and** extract the result at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Example with 1 match capturing the parts using groups:

```
((?:\d+\,\s*){4}\d+),\s*(.+)
```

Usage in a shellscript with perl:

```
$ echo '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10' | perl -p -e 's/((?:\d+\,\s*){4}\d+),\s*(.+)/One: [\1], Another: [\2]/' 
One: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], Another: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

https://regex101.com/r/hL0eH7/2

But I wouldn't use a regex for this, usually you are better of with your programming language's string processing functions.